# Quarkus Panache Reactive - select single column

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache, hibernate-reactive, quarkus-reactive

With the reactive version of panache I am unable to select a specific column from table using the project

```
    @Entity
   class Test: PanacheEntity(){
     @Column(name="amount")
     var amount: Double = 0.0
    
     @Column(name="name")
     lateinit var name: String
   }

 @ApplicationScoped
   class TestRepository: PanacheRepository<Test> {
     fun getSum(name: String) =
        find("select sum(l.amount) as amount from Test l where l.name = :name",Paramater().with("name", name)
        .project(Result::class)
        .singleResult()
   }

  data class Result(val amount: Double)
```

For sum reason this is generating an incorrect SQL statement
i.e.

```
SELECT new org.package.Result(amount) select sum(l.amount) as amount from org.package.Test l where l.name = $1
```

It never uses the projection. Is there another way to get the single value from the SQL which is not the entity being used? any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: The issue has been fixed and included in Quarkus 2.12.CR1

[I've reported the issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/26284).

As a workaround, you can remove the `.project(Result.class)` and run the following query:

```java
select new org.package.Result(sum(l.amount) as amount) from Test l where l.name = :name
```

The method will look like this:

```java
   @ApplicationScoped
   class TestRepository: PanacheRepository<Test> {
     fun getSum(name: String) =
        find("select new org.package.Result(sum(l.amount) as amount) from Test l where l.name = :name",Paramater().with("name", name)
        .singleResult()
   }
```

Comment: That did not work. It generates this error -> `parse() - HQL: SELECT new org.package.Result () select new org.package.Result(sum(l.amount)) from org.package.Test l where l.name = :name group by l.name` `line 1:51: unexpected token: )` notice the double select statements

Comment: You need to remove the ‘.project()’. Check my answer. I’m pretty sure it works because I’ve tested it